# Positioning Images CSS DIV ID Tags

Tags: css, image, html

I am placing images on a page using div id tags, so far i have four lined up in a row across the top of the page, but when i come to place one under the image in the top left corner, it just goes under a picture in the middle instead. I have used float:left and clear:left but none of these seem to work. I need the id "facts" to be underneath the top left corner image which is "light" any help?? This is my code so far -

HTML

```
<div id="light"><img src="harrypotter/harrylightening.png"/></div>
<div id="kiss"><img src="harrypotter/ronkiss.png"/></div>
<div id="keeper"><img src="harrypotter/keeper.jpg"/></div>
<div id="photo"><img src="harrypotter/photo.jpg"/></div>
<div id="facts"><img src="harrypotter/facts.jpg"/></div>
```

CSS

```
#light > img {
float:left;
height:447;
width:326;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:8px;
margin-right:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;

}

#kiss > img {
height:252;
width:336;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-right:5px;
float:left;

} 

#keeper > img {
height:234;
width:333;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-right:5px;
float:left;
}

#photo > img {
height:301;
width:225;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:5px; 
float:right;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your CSS could be more simple like this:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pcSz/)

```
div{
    float:left;
    margin:10px 5px 5px;
}
#light{
    margin-left:8px;
}
#photo{
    float:right;
    margin-right:0;
}
#facts{
    clear:left;
}
```

and about your problem, you must set `float` to `div`s not to images.

with your CSS you can use this:

```
#facts{
    clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your page is dynamic, you can try this code, every fifth elemnt should be come below the left element

HTML

```
<div><div id="light" class="img-class"><img src="harrypotter/harrylightening.png"/></div>
<div id="kiss"  class="img-class"><img src="harrypotter/ronkiss.png"/></div>
<div id="keeper" class="img-class"><img src="harrypotter/keeper.jpg"/></div>
<div id="photo" class="img-class"><img src="harrypotter/photo.jpg"/></div>
<div id="facts" class="img-class"><img src="harrypotter/facts.jpg"/></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.img-class {float:left;width:100px;height:100px;margin-bottom:15px;padding:0 10px;}.img-class:nth-child(5)  {clear:left;}
```